# skipping error "undefined columns selected" in lapply

Tags: r, lapply

Consider the following simple dataset `ds`:

```
ds <- data.frame("x"=c(1,2,3), "y"=c(5,5,5))
```

I apply a function on some columns of ds like `x` and `y` and create two new variables named `xnew` and `ynew`. It works well:

```
ds[,c("xnew","ynew")] <- lapply(ds[,c("x","y")], function(x) x^2)
```

But suppose there ist some undefined column names like `z`! In this case I get the error `"undefined columns selected"` and nither `xnew` nor `ynew` were created.
Is there any way to skip this error and create `xnew` and `ynew` and get only an error for `znew`? (something like `trycatch` by `for-loops`)

```
    ds[,c("xnew","ynew","znew")] <- lapply(ds[,c("x","y","z")], function(x) x^2)

    Error in `[.data.frame`(ds, , c("x", "y", "z")) : 
    undefined columns selected
```

Comment: Sounds like you're trying to solve an XY problem, more details on why you try to apply on unknown columns is needed to give proper advice

Comment: Try: `lapply(ds[,colnames(ds) %in% c("x","y","z")], function(x) x^2)`

Comment: @ Tensibai I am writing an R script and some variables are not gathered at the moment and comes later so I want to write the script including those variables too instead of modify the script later :-)

Comment: @ GKi thanks for your Suggestion but this gives the value of xnew to znew!

Comment: @Fateta No, it gives a list! Which you can bind to `ds` like: `tt <- lapply(ds[,colnames(ds) %in% c("x","y","z")], function(x) x^2); ds[,paste0(names(tt), "_new")]  <- tt`

Comment: @ GKi sorry I didn't understand you correctly earlier! You are absolutely right! useful comment!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define the lapply argument columns (oldvars) as the intersection between the column names of ds (x, y) and a vector that may include undefined column names (x, y, z). For the record, the data.table package incorporates an elegant internal lapply functionality which will be faster than base R for large datasets.

**Code**

```
ds = data.table(ds)

oldvars = intersect(c('x', 'y', 'z'), colnames(ds))
newvars = paste0(oldvars, '_new')

ds[, (newvars) := lapply(.SD, function(x) x^2), .SDcols = oldvars]
```

The last line applies the lapply statement onto a data.table subset (.SD), whereby the subset columns are declared using the .SDcols argument (in this case, x and y).

Using base R instead of data.table (from OPs comment):

```
ds[ ,newvars] <- lapply(ds[ ,oldvars], function(x) x^2)
```

**Result:**

```
> ds
   x y x_new y_new
1: 1 5     1    25
2: 2 5     4    25
3: 3 5     9    25
```

Comment: Using the intersection is a great idea thanks! It works even without data.table ds[ ,newvars] <- lapply(ds[ ,oldvars], function(x) x^2)

Comment: Good point. I added your base R lapply statement as well for future reference :-)